# Tab- or application-wide keyboard layout persistence

Tags: keyboard-layout, browser, ibus, fcitx, compose-key

**Problem description:** I normally have to write in several languages, so I use a different layout for each, having English International as default. While `fcitx` normally remembers the layout for each application, this is not the case with web browsers. Whenever I reload a page or change of input (e.g. content-editable div, texbox, textarea, etc.), the keyboard layout is automatically reset to English. The same happens when switching tabs or when the control logic erasers the content of the control. Although I can switch back, this is becoming very annoying. For instance, when using a chat interface (e.g. whatsapp, facebook messenger, google hangouts), the kb layout resets automatically with each and every message sent.

I've tried with `ibus` but simply does not work for me. For some reason I can neither switch layouts with the keyboard nor use the Compose key with `ibus`. I'm open to other input methods, but when possible I would continue using `fcitx`.

**Question:** What can I do (and how) to prevent `fcitx` to switching back to English when browsing a particular tab?

**Context:** Xubuntu 16.04 with `fcitx` as kb input method for several languages. Compose key is a must. Installed browsers: Chrome and Firefox.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With such advanced use of different input methods, possibly standard Ubuntu would be a better choice for you. Ubuntu 16.04 has smooth integration of both IBus and Fcitx. In Ubuntu 18.04 the Fcitx integration is gone, but the desktop is well integrated with IBus. Can't tell for sure that switching to standard Ubuntu would help, but you may find it worth a try.